# Can't boot after installing Ubuntu 18.0

Tags: boot, software-installation

I have installed Ubuntu at my office premises and I am facing issues
Many computers do not proceed to Desktop screen after ubuntu loads and display goes off after 4-5 minutes.

Also, I am not able to install Windows back as it does not allow Windows USB drive to boot

Please guide me how to fix this issue and also how I can completely remove partitions and install Windows back.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Try the above to troubleshoot Ubuntu. Windows isn't supported here and how to boot installation media is hardware specific. Please check your manual or online resources to learn how to change the boot order to the USB stick. Furthermore, I recommend using the official Microsoft Media Creation tool. If you need help with Windows please post at superuser.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: Also, is there any solution to problem I am facing that after installation it hangs on flash screen. I can go to recovery mode, is there something we can do.

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert a Ubuntu or any Linux install disk, select recovery, and try to partition the disk as NTFS from there. Afterwards, the disk should be read by a windows installer as a viable install HDD. use the below for help using the gparted formatting utility.

[Format USB drive to NTFS so it is usable under Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/934560/format-usb-drive-to-ntfs-so-it-is-usable-under-windows)

Comment: Bad suggestion - any OS installer can remove partitions and create the ones it needs - and the OP isn't there yet: *it does not allow Windows USB drive to boot* which means they can't or don't know how to prepare a Windows USB installer and/or change the boot order to boot from it.

Comment: I have had a lot of issues with Windows reading any partition that Linux has touched (especially Windows 10 and Server '12 R2) including removable media for a USB installer. but you make a good point that they are not there yet

Comment: I never had such problems but I disable the fast startup feature routinely. And I follow the good practices of avoiding writing to Windows partitions from another OS either way. But did it on a few occasions and nothing happened. Again, fast startup disabled is the key. If you need to share files between OSes it's better to have a separated NTFS formatted data partition.

Comment: I have tried to boot from Ubuntu USb disk and even with Windows bootable media it has same issue. I tried to boot with GParted it also got failed. I have same issue with 5 computers at least.