# Ubuntu 20.04 format HDD NTFS win 7 problem

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, ntfs

sort of newbie here:) I am still trying after few years to migrate to linux, but something always get wrong, so I go beck to win7:(

Now I trying ubuntu 20.04 and almost everything is working,... then..

I formatted (in Ubuntu) a new disk in ntfs for using it as data storage for both systems ubuntu and win7. After formatting I begin to store data on it. Then I boot in win7 and find out that win7 can access any data. After checking disk management I realize that win7 define unallocated disk space for the entire disk.

Cant find any answer online, so I m here to ask you:)

If cant get any answer here I think of formatting again, that time from win7.

bye
w

Comment: Look at the first answer in this question that will help you. https://askubuntu.com/questions/934560/format-usb-drive-to-ntfs-so-it-is-usable-under-windows#:~:text=You%20can%20format%20your%20device,set%20the%20type%20to%20ntfs

Comment: You are right @David, there is the answer. My mistake was formatting and partitioning w/o choosing MS-DOS. I solved the problem formatting again using Gparted instead Disks.