# Cannot use Rufus on Ubuntu 20.04 from wine or Windows VM

Tags: usb, virtualbox, wine, rufus

When I am trying to use rufus with wine, tt cannot detect any usb drive.

When I enter `winecfg` and `Drives` it does detect my usb as shown here:

[image: device appears as E: under /media]

What I want to do with Rufus is to make another live Kali Linux USB as per [this article](https://devanswers.co/kali-linux-live-usb-persistence-encryption-windows/).

Last time I made the live USB on another computer with Windows OS and everything worked just fine.

Now I am trying to make another live USB on my new PC running Ubuntu.

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

`lsusb` shows the device I want to use:

```
Bus 004 Device 013: ID xxxx:xxxx SanDisk Corp.  SanDisk 3.2Gen1
```

**Rufus and Wine Installation details**

I have downloaded the newest rufus version 3.15.1812 from [the official website](https://rufus.ie/en/)

I have downloaded  and installed wine with `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt-get wine`

`wine --version`

```
wine-5.0 (Ubuntu 5.0-3ubuntu1)
```

**Solutions I have tried**

- Changing the USB format from ext4 to NTFS that should be supported by Windows.
- Manually adding the USB to Wine with `winecfg`.
- Installing Windows as a guest machine on VirtualBox and trying to run Rufus there. It does detect my USB but I get another error:

  [image: the semaphore timeout period has expired]

  I have tried to solve this new issue by following few solutions from [this page](https://www.easeus.com/storage-media-recovery/the-semaphore-timeout-period-has-expired.html).

  I tried adding more RAM to the guest machine but it didn't help.

  I tried to reinstall Wine in a different way with a newer version wine-6.0.1 according to [this article](https://wine.htmlvalidator.com/install-wine-on-ubuntu-20.04.html).

How can I use Rufus successfully from Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: mkusb, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb, Will make a Live or Persistent Live USB. it has other options for working with USB's such as Disk Wiping. It will also create NTFS data partitions so the USB can still be used for data storage and transfer.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron I will try that out, either if that software will help me to make the usb i still want to figure out and solve the rufus issue.

Comment: I search all the bootable USB questions on Ask Ubuntu every day for the last ten years, and have not seen anybody answer that question. Good luck and please let us know if you find a solution. You can answer your own question. and I will upvote it also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rufus was successfully worked on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS Through Windows 10 VirtualBox.

[image: rufusWorked]

**Dependencies:**

VirtualBox Software could be installed [following this article](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-virtualbox-on-ubuntu)

Windows 10 OS installed on the VirtualBox could be installed [following this article](https://configurelaptop.eu/guide-windows-10-virtualbox-ubuntu/)

Enable USB Support via the virtual Windows OS could be done [following this topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/how-to-set-up-usb-for-virtualbox)

Newest Rufus software installed on the virtual windows OS could be downloaded from [the official site](https://rufus.ie/en/)

Now after following the above steps, your virtual windows is running and detecting your usb device you all ready to go.

**The Main Problem On The VM:**

"The semaphore timeout period has expired".

[image: semaphore timeout period]

**The Problem In Detailed:**

After making some research on the web i found the following reasons may cause the problem:

- Network connection problem when a file transfer depends on the connection.
- Opening a portable drive, for example, an external USB hard drive that is correctly connected to the computer.
- In our case we are talking about the portable drive/USB that is connected to our computer.

After deepening in front of the USB subject i found out the following reasons that can cause the specific error:

- Incompatible File System.
- A firewall or an anti-virus configuration that`s blocking the connection.
- A limited amount of RAM that`s not enough for completing the process.

**How Ensure Rufus Work On Windows VM:**

First configure your VM with enough RAM:

- Open your VM -> Head To Settings.

[image: firstStep]

- Head to System -> Motherboard.

[image: secondStep]

- I recommend to assign at least 8GB RAM or (if less) half of your computer ram amount.

Second launch into your virtual os and disable firewall and anti-virus:

- In Windows 10/8.1/8/7, press "Windows + R" hotkeys to bring up the "Run" box, input control to open Control Panel.

[image: Run]

- In the Control Panel, type firewall in the search, and click the "Windows Firewall" in the results.

[image: controlPanel]

- On the left pane, click "Turn Windows Firewall on or off".

[image: firewall]

- On the left pane, click "Turn Windows Firewall on or off".

[image: rules]

Third Perform A Clean Boot of your VM and Host:

- In Windows 10/8.1/8/7, press "Windows + R" hotkeys to bring up the "Run" box, input msconfig to open System Configuration.

[image: msconfig]

- Switch from the default General tab to "Services", tick the box "Hide all Microsoft Services". Click "OK".

[image: steps]

- Shut down your VM and Reboot your computer.

Fourth and last make sure your USB is NTFS type:

- Can be done follow to [this topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/934560/format-usb-drive-to-ntfs-so-it-is-usable-under-windows)

**Clarification:**

The whole solution is based on reading material and articles that are found all over the internet combining trial and error.

In my answer I have compiled material and even quotes and pictures from the  [following article](https://www.easeus.com/storage-media-recovery/the-semaphore-timeout-period-has-expired.html) that provided by EaseUS website.

The main purpose of this answer is to add certain steps that are not specified in the attached guides and to concentrate all the information and guides on one accessible page.

**Important:**

I may have missed a sub-step or sub-action that promotes a solution and I would be happy for comments on this answer if you encounter problems, in order to edit the solution and allow everyone to use the software.